# Changing Kendo window title's tooltip at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window, kendo-tooltip

I wanted to find out how I can update the tooltip for the kendo window title that is updated at runtime. I am able to update the window title using this code:

```
var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
dialog.title("Hello");
```

The problem arises when the title becomes a little too long.

```
var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
dialog.title("Hello this is a very long title that I was using to test the title strip");
```

I understand that the title in this case gets stripped when the window is opened. So as to tackle this situation I want to add a tooltip which shows the entire title text when hovering. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by ` gets stripped `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('.k-window-title').attr('title', dialog.title());
```